# Select current button that is showing in UIScrollView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with paging enabled. In every page I have a button. I want that with every swipe the button that is showing in the `UIScrollView` will be selected.

I'm guessing that the solution will be based on

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

but how can I know which button is showing without too many calculations of the range & offset?

Thanks

Comment: You can get current page with `UIPageControl` and the get All the `SubViews` From the `View`. ?

Comment: You want to select button in the current page or new page?

Comment: I have 5 pages. When I swipe from page 3 to page 4 at the end of the swipe I want that the button on page 4 will be selected \ pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to set a tag for each UIButton from your UIScrollView that is equal with the pageNumber+1 (+1 because for the page 0 the tag will be 1 and all the defaults tags are 0 so you can find the button). Then you can compute the tag in `viewDidEndDecelerating/viewDidScroll` or other scroll view delegate methods, depending on want you need. I'm doing  the all the computation in `viewDidEndDecelerating` something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;
    //now you have the current page so you can get the button 
    UIButton *button =(UIButton *) [scrollView viewWithTag:page+1]; //the +1 that I was talking about above
   button.selected = YES;
}
```

Also you may want to deselect the other buttons, so you can find them also by tags something like:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=numberOfPages; i++) { 
     UIButton *button =(UIButton *) [scrollView viewWithTag:i];
     button.selected = NO;
  }
```

But make sure you call the `for` loop before the part where you are enable the button.